# Second 60 days tourist visa Indonesia

Tags: visas, indonesia, visa-runs

I want to go to Indonesia for 4 months to travel, I am a dutch citizen and getting a 60 days tourist visa in the Netherlands.

I am planning on booking a ticket to Singapore to visit universal studio's and obtain another 60 days tourist visa there.

Will they give out the 60 days tourist visa if I already have a 60 days tourist visa from a couple days back?

Comment: I don't know about Indonesia specifically, usually when a country says you can stay for X days, they mean you can stay for X days and then go away for a while, not that you can stay for X days, and then another X and then another X and then... actually what's the point of having that limit of X days in the first place if we keep letting them back in after a day in the country next door?

Comment: Why do you want to leave the country and get a new visa, rather than just extending the visa while you're there?

Comment: Do you mean you are applying for a visa before travelling, or that you want to enter visa-free for 30 days, extend that for a further 30 days and then do a visa run to return on the same basis? The info I’ve seen indicates a return/onward ticket is required for the latter, implying visa runs may not be possible http://visa4indonesia.nl/visa-information/visa-on-arrival/

Comment: @Sneftel I want to visit universal studio's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer:yes
I did this many time

Nothing in immigration law forbid it, but you must be ready for a few nosy question at the custom. They'll want to check you are not working illegaly in Indonesia